# Shuffle ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, android

Read carefully before marking duplicate or downvoting.

My Requirement is to shuffle Arraylist of object keeping the list data same just changing the position.
I have an of type Dummydata :

```
List<DummyData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

My DummyData class has three String fields.

```
So adding some data for clarification:

dataList.add(new DummyData("Item1","Price1","Discount1"));
dataList.add(new DummyData("Item2","Price2","Discount2"));
dataList.add(new DummyData("Item3","Price3","Discount3"));
dataList.add(new DummyData("Item4","Price4","Discount4"));
dataList.add(new DummyData("Item5","Price5","Discount5"));
```

When I use Collections.shuffle(dataList);

the output is :

```
Item5 Price3 Discount4
Item2 Price1 Discount2
and some random output like this everytime.
```

My intended output is :

```
Item2 Price2 Discount2
Item5 Price5 Discount5
Item1 Price1 Discount1
```

Just the position should change list data should not jumble.
so my question is this possible to achieve using Collections.shuffle or not??

Comment: What is `dataList`? It can't be a java.util.ArrayList, since it has no add method that takes 3 arguments.

Comment: Encapsulate each of these three items together in a container. Then shuffle the list of these containers.

Comment: Eran is exactly right, your code cannot work as you described, thus you did not describe your actual problem, thus nobody can help you without using a crystal ball.

Comment: *Read carefully before marking duplicate or downvoting.* same result

Comment: @SHG I didn't get your approach of Encapsulating items in a container and the shuffle. Can you please explain further??

Comment: read the above comments

Comment: what about above comments @ScaryWombat

Comment: They explain why your question is getting downvoted - the code you have supplied would not even compile.

Comment: Create another class having three fields `ItemNo., Price, Discount` Then create a list of the object of that class. Then use `Collections.shuffle()` method on that list. Retrieve objects from that list. For each object retrieve other data from it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have provided the necessary code required to answer the question and my code is compiling fine and I also shared the results I was getting

Comment: Please show a link to the javadocs where `add` with 3 parameters `dataList.add("Item1","Price1","Discount1");` would work

Comment: @ScaryWombat have you ever heard of CustomList of type class. Don't just blabber anything. See the answer below for List of type Product class
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>(); Read yourself before commenting.

Comment: Yes, the answer below gives `products.add(new Product("Watch", 45.99, 9.99));` see how it is instantiating a new `Product` before trying to add it as a single parameter.  Your code is trying to add 3 `String` paramaters - BTW, you seem to be a very angry young man.

Comment: Sorry man @ScaryWombat I was really frustrated why people were downvoting my question. I am not a newbie I was adding the data same way by creating new object everytime of my data class. Here I provided the code which I thought would be necessary for people to provide a solution to my problem. I didn't thought they'll downvote if I don't write each and everyLine of my code.

Comment: Well to be honest starting your question off with *Read carefully before marking duplicate or downvoting.* is going to annoy a lot of people if **you** don't post carefully.  The first comment highlighted the problem with your code and you seemed to ignore it and went on the offensive. Nothing more to say.

Comment: @sumit This comment is not meant for this question, its just to clarify the downvote you have done for one of my post, First know that `postDelayed` function of handler class is not static, which cannot be reference by `Handler.postDelayed(..)` instead you have to create an object of Handler class and call the method `new Handler().postDelayed(..`, learn some basics, and then downvote.

Comment: @sumit hope this makes sense to you now.

Comment: @Sanoop sorry I missed that I was about to correct myself till then he deleted the post. That was just a silly mistake on my side.

Comment: @sumit No issues :) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi Sumit i dont know why there are few downvote it is because you have not informed that you are new to Java Language
Please find my answer below

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

final class Product {
    private final String name;
    private final Double price;
    private final Double discount;

    Product(String name, Double price, Double discount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", discount=" + discount + "}";
    }
}

public final class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        products.add(new Product("Watch", 45.99, 9.99));
        products.add(new Product("Keyboard", 21.99, 3.99));
        products.add(new Product("Mouse", 99.99, 4.99));

        System.out.println("Original items Before shuffle are");
        products.forEach(System.out::println);

        Collections.shuffle(products);
        System.out.println("Original items After shuffle are");
        products.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sector11 problem with my code was I was using ArrayList instead of LinkedList.

Comment: Don't know why they have downvoted when I provided all the necessary information that was required to answer the question.

Comment: @sumit update for ArrayList and yes they have rights to downvote your question is NOT AT ALL CLEAR!!

Comment: they have rights I know but in what Aspect is my question not clear to understand

Comment: You were not clear on your approach, anyways lets agree that you have a solution back to work!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Collections.shuffle(dataList);
Log.d(TAG,dataList.toString());
```

Working use your logic

```
   Collections.shuffle(dataList);
    ArrayList<DummyData> l1=new ArrayList<>();
    for(DummyData e : dataList){
        l1.add(e);
    }
    Log.d(TAG,l1.toString());
```

Comment: do you know the output of l1.toString()?